# Catch phone call, but let the phone activity in background

Tags: android, google-glass

I have source code that get a phone call and accept it. But my activity goes to background, and on front is the call one. Is there any way to send a broadcast to the call method to send it programmatically or some work around to see again my activity or a new one?

What I need is to take the call but not show the screen to the user, to use this on Google glass and make only voice commands... any idea?